# How to unregister specific onareatouch

Tags: andengine

```
  shell[0]=new TiledSprite (CAMERA_WIDTH*35/200,(CAMERA_HEIGHT*25)/40,shell_image, getVertexBufferObjectManager())
   {
       int house_name=0;
       int temp=house_name;
       int current=0;
       int num_houses=8;
    @Override
    public boolean onAreaTouched(TouchEvent pSceneTouchEvent,
            float pTouchAreaLocalX, float pTouchAreaLocalY) {
        switch(pSceneTouchEvent.getAction()){
        case TouchEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            current=shell[0].getCurrentTileIndex();         
            temp=house_name;
            TimerHandler timer =  new TimerHandler(1, true,  new ITimerCallback() {
                int i=0;
                int last=current;
                @Override
                public void onTimePassed(TimerHandler pTimerHandler) {

                     if((i<1)&&(temp==house_name))
                         shell[house_name].setCurrentTileIndex(0);

                    if((i==last) && (shell[temp].getCurrentTileIndex()>0)&&(temp!=7))
              {
                      current=shell[temp].getCurrentTileIndex()+1;
                      shell[temp].setCurrentTileIndex(0);
                      last=current;
                      i=0;
                  }
                        if(i>0)
                        {
                            shell[temp].setCurrentTileIndex(shell[temp].getCurrentTileIndex()+1);
                        }
                        temp++;
                        if(temp>=num_houses){
                            temp=0;
                        }


                  if(i == current)
                      unregisterUpdateHandler(pTimerHandler);
                    // unregister your timer
                  i++;
                }

                });

            shell[0].registerUpdateHandler(timer); 
                               break;
        }
        return super
                .onAreaTouched(pSceneTouchEvent, pTouchAreaLocalX, pTouchAreaLocalY);
    } 
   };
```

How can I unregister a touch area so that it wont be touched again while running? shell is an array. and i also want those other tiled sprite to not be ontouch while running. Please do help me. This is a mancala game in Philippines which is called Sungka.

Answer (score 0):

To do that, you need to unregister the touch areas of your Sprite from the scene. Like this:

```
scene.unregisterTouchArea(sprite);
```

Answer (score 0):

Also you can just store a boolean variable for running ('boolean isRunning = true:') when your sprite is running, and check this variable during Touch events.